# if else Sorting program not sorting correctly

Tags: java, sorting, if-statement

I'm having trouble with a simple sorting program. This program is meant to take in 3 integers from a user and sort them correctly from smallest to largest. It works fine if it is the largest but it won't work if it isn't.

Code:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int c = 0;
int a1 = 0;
int b1 = 0;
int c1 = 0;


System.out.print("Please enter the first interger:");
a = keyboard.nextInt();
System.out.print("Please enter the second interger:");
b = keyboard.nextInt();
System.out.print("Please enter the third interger:");
c = keyboard.nextInt();

if(a > b || a > c){
    c1 = a;

    if(b < c){
        a1 = b;
        b1 = c; 
    }
    else if(b > c){
        b1 = b;
        a1 = c;     
    }
}       
else if((a < b || a > c) && (a < c || a > b)){
    b1 = a;

    if(c > b){
        a1 = b;
        c1 = c;
    }
    else if(b > c){
        a1 = c;
        c1 = b;
    }
}
else if(a < b || a < c){
    a1 = a;

    if(b < c){
        b1 = b;
        c1 = c;
    }           
    else if(b > c){
        b1 = c;
        c1 = b;
    }
}

System.out.println("The variables in order of smallest to largest is"
                      + "a=" + a1 + " b=" + b1 + " c="  + c1);
```

Example:

```
Please enter the first interger:2
Please enter the second interger:3
Please enter the third interger:1
The variables in order of smallest to largest is a=1 b=3 c=2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your logical OR and AND conditions completely backwards in all of your conditions.  E.g. In your first `if` statement, if `a` is greater than `b` AND `a` is greater than `c`, then you want to assign `c1` the value of `a` (the greatest).  Also, what if all the values are the same?  Then no conditions are satisfied, and zeros are printed.  Use `<=` and `>=`.

```
if (a >= b && a >= c) {
```

Use `<=` and `>=` for the inner conditions of each block also.

This continues in the second outer `else if`, when you want `a` to be between `b` and `c`, whether b <= a <= c or c <= a <= b.

```
else if ((a <= b && a >= c) || (a <= c && a >= b)) {
```

And continuing to the last condition:

```
else if (a <= b && a <= c) {
```

However, that will always be true if you get here, because the other 2 conditions above it are false, so a simple `else` is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is overly complicated. By definition, `a1` is the minimum of `a`, `b` and `c`. While `c1` is the maximum of `a`, `b` and `c`. I'd use `Math.min` and `Math.max` to compute them. Next, the middle term is (by definition) the one that isn't `a1` or `c1`. We can compute that by adding all the terms together and then subtracting the smallest and largest. Finally, I would prefer `printf` (and formatted IO). Something like,

```
int a1 = Math.min(c, Math.min(a, b));
int c1 = Math.max(c, Math.max(a, b));
int b1 = a + b + c - a1 - c1;
System.out.printf("The variables in order of smallest to largest are "
        + "a=%d, b=%d, c=%d%n", a1, b1, c1);
```